# Two formats for contacts in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I'm using Outlook 2010 on Windows 7. Most of my contacts look like this, which is how I want them:

[image: Contact how I want it to appear]

However, some of my contacts look like this instead:

[image: Strange contact format]

Why is this, and how can I make all my contacts look like the first screenshot?

Comment: Looks like the screen shots are from different PCs

Comment: (are these both from the same computer?

Comment: Yes same computer same outlook, just different contacts.

Comment: Are both these 'contacts' from the same contacts folder?  Or are you trying to compare a contact in your personal contacts against a contact in a public folder, or from a Global address list?  In outlook it is possible to build new forms and items.  It is completely possible to replace the standard contacts form for a specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Are both these 'contacts' from the same contacts folder?  Or are you trying to compare a contact in your personal contacts against a contact in a public folder, or from a Global address list?

In Outlook it is possible to build new forms and items.  It is completely possible to replace the standard contacts form for a specific folder.

Perhaps you or someone built a custom contact form and placed it in the Organization Form Library.  Perhaps some of your contacts are based on a different form.

Anyway, if these contacts are in a public folder, there may not be anything you can do about them.

If they are in a folder in your mailbox, then simply export them as csv, or some other format, then re-import them.

Here are some links about Outlook custom forms:

- FAQ about custom forms and Outlook - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146636
- Creating custom forms - http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/tutorial-creating-and-distributing-custom-forms-with-outlook-HA001210610.aspx
- http://www.outlookcode.com/
- http://www.outlook-tips.net/2011/1547/using-outlook-forms-designer/

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an answer to your question over the past week. The only thing I could think of is that these contacts where possibly emailed, copied or imported from Outlook 2000 or Outlook 2003 when you upgraded or upgraded to Outlook 2010.

Depending on the number of contacts with this problem, you can backup all contacts, check that the fields and file types are the same as the correctly-installed contacts, then refill to the correct Outlook contacts' information sheet using 'copy and paste' from the Outlook data file to a Notepad 'text only' file, then save and paste back to Outlook.

You could also [backup all contacts, then re-import normally again](http://www.gilsmethod.com/how-to-import-your-contacts-into-outlook-2010). You may have to use a [file converter](http://www.ehow.com/how_14637_import-contacts-file.html#ixzz1XndlpR7u).

I only have Outlook 2007 and this is all I could find.